# Checkbox Filters on XML Generated Google Map

Tags: javascript, xml, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, checkbox

I am having a hard time trying to setup checkbox filters for the following code, which is reduced because the whole thing is massive. Everything works, except these checkbox filters. The markers are all being pulled from a php generated xml file like in Googles example.

I think it's because of the marker file being a *object HTMLCollection* and I'm getting *markers[i].setVisible is not a function* I've tried many things but it's beyond my knowledge. I'd really appreciate some help with this one, the last step for me.

Example XML data

```
<marker name="Some Shop" id="2" type="shops" description="Great shop" street_number="350" street_name="Main Road" suburb="Lovely ville" lat="-23.9544011" lng="156.1895873" from="2014-01-01 01:00:00" to="2015-10-01 01:00:00"/>
```

Javascript

```
downloadUrl("xml_generator.php", function (data) {

                var xml = data.responseXML;

                var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");

                for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {

                    var type = markers[i].getAttribute("type");

                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        map: map,
                        position: point,
                        icon: icon.icon
                    });

                    bindInfoBox(marker, map, ib, myOptions);

                }

        $(document).ready(function(){
        // == shows all markers of a particular category, and ensures the checkbox is checked ==
        function show(category) {
            window.alert("Show " + category + markers);
            for (var i=0; i<markers.length; i++) {
                if (markers[i].getAttribute("type") == category) {
                    markers[i].setVisible(true);
                }
            }
        }

        // == hides all markers of a particular category, and ensures the checkbox is cleared ==
        function hide(category) {
            window.alert("Hide " + category);
            for (var i=0; i<markers.length; i++) {
                if (markers[i].getAttribute("type") == category) {
                    markers[i].setVisible(true);
                }
            }

        }

        $(".toggle").click(function(){
            var cat = $(this).attr("value");
            // If checked
            if ($(this).is(":checked"))
            {
                show(cat);
            } else
            {
                hide(cat);
            }
        });

    });

            });
```

Then the HTML checkbox

```
<input value="shops" class="toggle" type="checkbox" checked="yes">
```

Comment: related question [Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Element> has no method 'getPosition'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20446127/uncaught-typeerror-object-element-has-no-method-getposition)

Comment: related question: [Google Maps / JavaScript - display certain markers - MySQL backend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21582678/google-maps-javascript-display-certain-markers-mysql-backend)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`markers[i]` is an HTMLElement object (or XMLElement).  It doesn't have a setVisible method.

You want a different "gmarkers" array of google.maps.Marker objects like is created below:

```
            var xml = data.responseXML;

            var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");

            for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {

                var type = markers[i].getAttribute("type");

                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    map: map,
                    position: point,
                    icon: icon.icon
                });

                bindInfoBox(marker, map, ib, myOptions);
                gmarkers.push(marker);  //*****

            }
```

Comment: I tried that, and declared gmarkers at the start of the code where map is declared but no luck. Also updated the functions. Getting the error *Cannot read property 'push' of undefined*

Comment: I declared gmarkers under var markers, before the for statement as *var gmarkers = [];* but now getting the error *Cannot read property 'setCenter' of undefined*

Comment: Got it! Decleared gmarkers back at the start, and changed markers[i].setVisible(true); to gmarkers[i].setVisible(true); and it all worked.